# Is there a way decrypt a sentence wrote with numbers that have letter values in a dictionary?

Tags: python

I need to "translate" a sentence wrote with numbers (such as "112233"), using a dictionary which assigns 2 numbers to a letter

So this is the dictionary:

```
code_2 = {14: 'a', 15: 'b', 16: 'c', 24: 'd', 25: 'e', 26: 'f', 34: 'g', 35: 
'h', 36: 'i', 44: 'j', 45: 'k', 46: 'l',
 54: 'm', 55: 'n', 56: 'ñ', 64: 'o', 65: 'p', 66: 'q', 74: 'r', 75: 's',
 76: 't', 84: 'u', 85: 'v', 86: 'w', 94: 'x', 95: 'y', 96: 'z'}
```

I've tried to separate a given sentence (like 141516) every 2 numbers, so it returns this: 14 15 16
My goal would be to be able to translate a code written in numbers to a sentence with letter, for example if someone writes "3525464664" I would like the program to return it's translation using the dictionary above ( "hello")

this is the function I've found

```
def codification(words,code_2):

    result=''

    for letter in words:

        if letter in code_2:

            result= result+str(code_2[letter])

        else:

            result= result+letter

    return result


sentence= input('Write:')


print (str(codification(sentence,code_2)))
```

I've also found a way to separate a series of numbers into groups of 2 numbers with the following code:

```
def encrypt(code, lenght):


    return ' '.join(code[i:i+lenght] for i in range(0,len(code),lenght))



code= input()



print(encrypt(str(code),2))
```

I've no idea on how to solve this problem so if anyone can help me i would be very grateful

**[EDIT]: Is there a way in which I could translate 2 or more words? For example, "3525464664 267436255524" ("hello friend"). Because in with the code given below if I try to do this I get an Error message.**

Comment: Thanks for all the edits, I wasn't sure on how to wirte code with the right format in this site :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

1. Split the string in a list of two numbers (that assumes the keys in `code_2` are always number with two digits).
2. Iterate over the previous list and select the value in `code_2`.

As well, I use the `"".join(my_list)` method to transform a `list` to a `string`. Some explanations [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join)

```
# Your dict
code_2 = {14: 'a', 15: 'b', 16: 'c', 24: 'd', 25: 'e', 26: 'f', 34: 'g',
         35:'h', 36: 'i', 44: 'j', 45: 'k', 46: 'l', 54: 'm', 55: 'n',
         56: 'ñ', 64: 'o', 65: 'p', 66: 'q', 74: 'r', 75: 's', 76: 't',
         84: 'u', 85: 'v', 86: 'w', 94: 'x', 95: 'y', 96: 'z'}


def decode_word(text):
    # Split to a list of 2 numbers
    text_l = ["".join([a,b]) for a,b in zip(text[::2], text[1::2])]

    # Rebuild the world
    return "".join([code_2[int(key)] for key in text_l])


print(decode_word("3525464664"))
# hello
```

If you want to make it **safer**, you can use:

```
def decode_word(text):
    # Check then length or the string
    if len(text) %2 != 0:
        raise ValueError("Text incorrect (must have a even length)")

    # Split to a list of 2 numbers
    text_l = ["".join([a,b]) for a,b in zip(text[::2], text[1::2])]

    # Rebuild the world
    word = "".join([code_2.get(int(key), "") for key in text_l])

    # Check if all keys have been found
    if len(word) < len(text)//2:
        print("WARNING: Some keys doesn't belong to 'code_2'.")
    return word
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! It worked perfectly, I can't believe I got an answer so quickly. I'm new in the programming word.

Comment: Glad to help you ! Feel free to accept the answer if that solves your question and upvote/downvote according how helpful the answer is. Some reading after you got answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Cheers.